# MongoDB aggregate merging fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo Database I'll like to "join" two of them and then merge some other fields:
Let's see the schemas:

Students Schema (and data):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fbd564981b1313de790b580"),
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": "21",
    "image": "https://XXXX/481.png",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5fbd4e6881b1313de790b56b"),
            "passed": true,
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5fcb63fa8814d96876c687bf"),
        }
    ],
    "__v": NumberInt("1"),
}
```

and Subject schema:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fbd4e6881b1313de790b56b"),
    "course": 3,
    "teacher": "John Smith",
    "name": "Math",

},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fcb63fa8814d96876c687bf"),
    "name": "IT",
    "course": 8,
    "teacher": "John Peter",

}
```

What I'll like to make a query with the subjects (all info) of a student, also if the student have additional fields in subject like `passed` add it to the subject subdocument.

Here is my query till now:

```
db.students.aggregate([
{
    $match: 
        {
            _id : ObjectId('5fbd564981b1313de790b580')
        }
},
{
    $lookup : 
        {
            from : "subjects",
            localField : "subjects._id",
            foreignField : "_id", 
            as : "FoundSubject"
        }
}
]);
```

which correctly make the "join" but the merge is still missing, I got as result:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fbd564981b1313de790b580"),
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": "21",
    "image": "https://XXXX/481.png",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5fbd4e6881b1313de790b56b"),
            "passed": true,
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5fcb63fa8814d96876c687bf"),
        }
    ],
    "__v": NumberInt("1"),
    "FoundSubject": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5fbd4e6881b1313de790b56b"),
            "course": 3,
            "teacher": "John Smith",
            "name": "Math"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5fcb63fa8814d96876c687bf"),
            "name": "IT",
            "course": 8,
            "teacher": "John Peter"
        }
        
    ]
}
```

but I'll like to have:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fbd564981b1313de790b580"),
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": "21",
    "image": "https://XXXX/481.png",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5fbd4e6881b1313de790b56b"),
            "course": 3,
            "teacher": "John Smith",
            "name": "Math",
            "passed": true,
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5fcb63fa8814d96876c687bf"),
            "name": "IT",
            "course": 8,
            "teacher": "John Peter"
        }
    ],
    "__v": NumberInt("1"),
}
```

with merged data and field "passed" added. How can accomplish that?
I'm new to MongoDB coming from MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge both objects, add below stage after `$lookup`,

**MongoDB Version From 3.4**

- `$map` to iterate loop of `students` array
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `FoundSubject` array, check condition if condition match then return required fields otherwise return initial value
- `$project` to remove `FoundSubject` from result

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      subjects: {
        $map: {
          input: "$subjects",
          as: "s",
          in: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$FoundSubject",
              initialValue: {},
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$s._id", "$$this._id"] },
                  {
                    _id: "$$this._id",
                    course: "$$this.course",
                    name: "$$this.name",
                    teacher: "$$this.teacher",
                    passed: "$$s.passed"
                  },
                  "$$value"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { FoundSubject: 0 } }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OPn48UrTnpZ)

---

**MongoDB Version From 4.4**

- `$map` to iterate loop of `students` array,
- `$filter` to get matching document from `FoundSubject` array and `$first` to get first object from array returned by filter
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current objects with found result object from filter
- remove `FoundSubject` using `$$REMOVE`

```
  // skipping your stages
  {
    $addFields: {
      FoundSubject: "$$REMOVE",
      subjects: {
        $map: {
          input: "$subjects",
          as: "s",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$s",
              {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$FoundSubject",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$s._id", "$$this._id"] }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oAPpn0_D50s)

Comment: Works fine on the playground, but on my database got that error: > [Error] Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'  Could be  databse version problem?

Comment: What is the version of your mongodb? and where you executing this query?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v3.4.24. Direcly from mongo shell : assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'",
        "code" : 168,
        "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14

DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js
2020-12-09T13:08:32.619+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'",

Comment: Okay $mergeObjects support from version 3.6 and also $first start from 4.4, i will update my answer for 3.4 version soon.

Comment: @MarcoMartin I have updated the answer for version 3.4 you can check.

Comment: ok, thanks! Should I upgrade mongodb to 4.4?

Comment: Its up to your project requirement, no need for this query only.